# Environment variables show undefined in React App

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have seen all posts on StackOverflow related to my problem statement. But none of them worked for me.
The following is my folder structure:
[image]

I have a variable named `REACT_APP_API_URL=some value` in the `config.env` file. In the `App.js` file I am trying to print out the variable `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)`. But it continues to show undefined.

Comment: try changing your env file to .env only and make sure you restart the server before testing if your enviroments is working... also dont forget to check if your .gitignore has your's .env files before commiting =)

Comment: I have tried to do the steps you mentioned. Still they show undefined. Is there anything to do with webpack?

Comment: shouldn't be anything to do with webpack... Maybe its because's your .env is not in the same level of your frontend folder? why dont you try moving it to your root /frontend

Comment: I created .env file in frontend folder, outside of src folder. Still it won't read.